# <no devices> in Android Studio 4.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, jetbrains-ide

I'm learning Flutter and I've just setup Android Studio. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSIhiZ5jRB0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=4) tutorial by Net Ninja. I'm at the point where I'm trying to run my `Android Emulator`, but it says `<no devices>` even though I've made a virtual device.[image: Virtual Devices]
I've been trying to debug to no avail.

Here is my virtual device details:

```
Name: Nexus_6_API_30
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_30.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 30)
Skin: nexus_6
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 6
hw.lcd.width: 1440
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 30
tag.id: google_apis
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 6 API 30
hw.gpu.mode: host
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: false
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 2
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 2560
vm.heapSize: 384
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Nexus_6_API_30
hw.lcd.density: 560
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:869d76256fcdae165862720ddb8343f9
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```